# spanning list and a linearly dependent set

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me understand this two notions:

What is the difference between a spanning list and a linearly dependent set? and is there any relationship between the two?

Comment: what do you mean by LI (linearly independent)?

Comment: Yes, L.I. is a common abbreviation for linearly independent.

Comment: @anon: But mohamez asked about linearly **dependent** sets.

Comment: $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is linearly independent but spans $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: Your question asks about linearly **dependent** sets, not linearly **independent** sets; which do actually mean?

Comment: You're right Brian. OP: there are subsets which are (a) LI and spanning (this is a basis), or (b) LI but not spanning (take a proper subset of a basis), or (c) not LI but spanning (add 0 to any basis), or (d) neither LI nor spanning (add 0 to any proper subset of a basis). So any of the four possibilities of LI / not LI versus spanning / not spanning are possible.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott what do you think of anon's $1$st comment?

Comment: I want to know whether it’s actually relevant. Did you ask the question that you meant to ask, or did you really want to know about linearly independent sets?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott it's anon's comment that rise up this LI matter

Comment: I’ve added a bit to my answer, so that it now answers both your original question and the one with linear independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space. A set $S\subseteq V$ spans $V$ if every vector in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $S$. $S$ is linearly dependent if some $v\in S$ is a linear combination of $S\setminus\{v\}$. If $v$ is any non-zero vector, the set $\{v,2v\}$ is linearly dependent, but it spans $V$ if and only if $\dim V=1$. Thus, in general a linearly dependent set need not span the space. On the other hand, if $B$ is a basis for $V$, then $B$ spans $V$ and is linearly **independent**, not linearly dependent.

On the other hand, if $v$ is any non-zero vector in a space of dimension greater than $1$, then $\{v\}$ is neither linearly dependent nor a spanning set, and on the other hand $V$ is both linearly dependent and a spanning set.

Thus, in general there is no relationship between the two concepts.

**Added:** In case you meant to ask about spanning sets and linearly **independent** sets, those concepts are also independent, as you may easily infer from the examples given above. However, they interact in an important way: a basis $B$ for $V$ is both a maximal linearly independent set and a minimal spanning set. That is, if you expand $B$ to include even one other vector, the new set is now linearly **dependent**, and if you remove even one vector from $B$, what’s left no longer spans $V$.